# how to get data of state by using country id in React Native

Tags: react-native

i have created a app in react native to show the detail first district then tehsil then village then show a specific base64 pdf in my app .those four thing are get in a different api on server how to connect those thing with a id please help

Answer (score -1):

you should use multiple states, and in every state, you store the district, the village and so on, that is coming from the API under the country you filtered